# saving blob picture into database without storing to hd

Tags: coldfusion, blob

I have an base64 picture string in coldfusion.

How can I save this image blob into the database without storing to filedisk?
My function.

```
<cfset base64string="base64picturestring">
<cfimage source="#ImageReadBase64("data:image/png;base64,#base64string#")#"
destination="c:\picture.png" action="write" overwrite="true">
<cffile action="readbinary" file="c:\picture.png" variable="ImageData"/>

INSERT INTO imagedb (imageblob)
VALUES (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob" value="#ImageData#" />)
```

But I don't want to save image on the hard drive.
I need this.

base64----imageblob----database

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the in-memory filesystem:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-70e2363b121825b20e7-8000.html#WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-540771bc12182683461-8000

```
<cfset base64string="base64picturestring">
<cfimage source="#ImageReadBase64("data:image/png;base64,#base64string#")#"
destination="ram://src/picture.png" action="write" overwrite="true">
<cffile action="readbinary" file="ram://src/picture.png" variable="ImageData"/>
<cffile action="delete" source = "ram://src/picture.png"> 

INSERT INTO imagedb (imageblob)
VALUES (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob" value="#ImageData#" />)
```

Comment: Ben's suggestion is a good one, but I wasn't sure if you were expecting the cfimage tag to do some work for you beyond simply reading the binary data back out.  If you do, then my answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
ToBinary('#yourString#')
```

Calculates the binary representation of Base64-encoded data